# I am finding an answer for multiplication table in C++/

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cout<<"The table of any number you want to print"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    
    for (int i = 1; i <=10; ++i)
    {
        cout<<n<<"*"<<i<<"="<<n*n<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am finding the solution of the problem.
and i just want to knnow that why it is not printing the value.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Well it should be `cout<<n<<"*"<<i<<"="<<n*i<<endl;`/ If you have `n*n` then you are just going to get the same number 10 times in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the for loop that prints the multiplication table should use **i** to calculate the product rather than **n**

Try :

```
    cout<<n<<"*"<<i<<"="<<n*i<<endl;
```